# $(X,\mu , \mathcal F)$ a measure space , $f:X\to\mathbb R$ measurable ; $\int_A f d\mu \ge 0 , \forall A \in \mathcal F$ , then $f \ge 0$ a.e.?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mu , \mathcal F)$ be a measure space and $f:X\to\mathbb R$ be a measurable function such that $\int_A f d\mu \ge 0 , \forall A \in \mathcal F$ , then is it true that $\mu \{x \in X : f(x)<0\}=0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\{x, f(x) <0\} = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{x, f(x) <-\frac{1}{n}\}.
\end{align*}
Then, you need only show that $\mu(\{x, f(x) <-\frac{1}{n}\})=0$ for all $n$, which is obvious.

Comment: Because if $A_k=\{x : f(x)<-1/k\}$ and $\mu(A_k)>0$ then $\int_{A_k} f d\mu \le -\dfrac {1}{k} \mu(A_k)<0$ , am I correct ?

Comment: yes. that is correct.